# Split elements of a list inside a list in python

Tags: python, list, split

I am new to Python. How can I make a single list out of many lists inside a list?
For example,

```
list1 = ['aplle', 'grape', ['aplle1', 'grape1'] ]
```

Output should be:

```
list1 = ['aplle', 'grape', 'aplle1', 'grape1']
```

The list has thousands of elements.

Comment: Does the order of the list matter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python

Comment: Yes, It does matter.

Comment: @Joonazan what does your link has to do with this question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flatten (an irregular) list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

use `flatten` in `compiler.ast`:

```
>>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>>> list1 = ['apple', 'grape', ['apple1', 'grape1', ['apple2', 'grape2'] ] ]
>>>> flattened_list = flatten(list1)
```

**Output**:
    ['apple', 'grape', 'apple1', 'grape1', 'apple2', 'grape2']

***This will work for multiple nesting levels***

PS: But this package has been removed in Python3

Comment: and is Deprecated since version 2.6

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to python too, so there's probably a simpler way, but this seems to work.

```
list1 = ['aplle', 'grape', ['aplle1', 'grape1'] ]
list2 = []
for x in list1:
    list2 += x if type(x) == list else [x]
print(list2)
```

This will not work if the list has elements that are themselves nested lists, but I think it meets the requirements of the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's worked

```
def main(lis):
    new_list = []
    for i in lis:
        if type(i) != list:
            new_list.append(i)
        else:
            for t in range(len(i)):
                new_list.append(i[t])
    return new_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(main([1,2,3,[4,5]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution for splitting elements of the list inside list in order of the list.

Input List :

```
list1 = ['aplle', 'grape', ['aplle1', 'grape1'],'apple3',['apple2','grape2'] ]
```

Here is the code:

```
for obj in list1:
    if type(obj) is list:
        i = list1.index(obj)
            for obj1 in obj:
                list1.insert(i,obj1)
            list1.remove(obj)
```

Ouput List in order as needed :

```
list1 = ['aplle', 'grape', 'grape1', 'aplle1', 'apple3', 'grape2', 'apple2']
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this solution from Cristian, it is very general.
[flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists-in-python)

```
def flatten(l):
import collections
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, (str, bytes)):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el


print(list(flatten(['aplle', 'grape', ['aplle1', 'grape1']])))

['aplle', 'grape', 'aplle1', 'grape1']
```